# No Wi-Fi Adapter found Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have tried every solution that I found on internet, but none of them worked.
I am using 5.0.0-37-generic kernel and running Ubuntu from my HP Notebook 15-db1103nm Laptop
Here is my wireless info:

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########
    Report from: 06 Dec 2019 22:30 CET +0100
    Booted last: 06 Dec 2019 00:00 CET +0100
    Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000
    ##### release ###########################

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
    Release:    18.04
    Codename:   bionic

    ##### kernel ############################

    Linux 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

    ##### desktop ###########################

    Ubuntu

    ##### lspci #############################

    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:85ea]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]

    04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0113] (rev 01)

    ##### lsusb #############################

    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:0235 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

    ##### rfkill ############################

    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

    ##### secure boot #######################

    'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

    ##### lsmod #############################

    cfg80211              679936  0
    compat                 16384  1 cfg80211
    hp_wmi                 16384  0
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
    wmi_bmof               16384  0
    wmi                    28672  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

    ##### interfaces ########################

    [/etc/network/interfaces]
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ##### ifconfig ##########################

    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
        inet 192.168.0.21/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
           valid_lft 3053sec preferred_lft 3053sec
        inet6 fe80::58ef:6375:63c1:8351/64 scope link noprefixroute 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    ##### iwconfig ##########################

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eno1      no wireless extensions.

    ##### route #############################

    default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000 
    192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.21 metric 100 

    ##### resolv.conf #######################

    [777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

    nameserver 127.0.0.53
    options edns0

    ##### network managers ##################

    Installed:

        NetworkManager

    Running:

    root       783     1  0 22:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    ##### NetworkManager info ###############

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/net/eno1
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c83eb0c8-2e39-3bc8-9301-b6ec6bce12c4
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
    GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.21/24
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
    IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
    IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             89.216.1.40
    IP4.DNS[2]:                             89.216.1.50
    DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 89.216.1.40 89.216.1.50
    DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.21
    DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        default_ip_ttl = 64
    DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       time_offset = 0
    DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
    DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
    DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
    DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
    DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1575670888
    DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
    DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_host_name = 1
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::58ef:6375:63c1:8351/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
    IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
    IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
    IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c83eb0c8-2e39-3bc8-9301-b6ec6bce12c4 | Wired connection 1

    ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true

    ##### NetworkManager config #############

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
    [connection]
    wifi.powersave = 3

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
    [ifupdown]
    managed=false
    [device]
    wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

    [[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
    [main]
    dns=systemd-resolved

    [[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
    [keyfile]
    unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

    [[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
    [connectivity]
    uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

    [[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
    [device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
    match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
    wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
    wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
    ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

    ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

    ##### Netplan config ####################

    [/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager

    ##### iw reg get ########################

    Region: Europe/Belgrade (based on set time zone)

    global
    country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

    ##### iwlist channels ###################

    lo        no frequency information.

    eno1      no frequency information.

    ##### iwlist scan #######################

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

    ##### module infos ######################

    [cfg80211]
    filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
    version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
    description:    wireless configuration support
    license:        GPL
    author:         Johannes Berg
    srcversion:     BCF157A5337A326CC2937B9
    depends:        compat
    retpoline:      Y
    name:           cfg80211
    vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
    parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
    parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
    parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

    ##### module parameters #################

    [cfg80211]
    bss_entries_limit: 1000
    cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
    ieee80211_regdom: 00

    ##### /etc/modules ######################

    ##### modprobe options ##################

    [/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
    blacklist microcode

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
    alias net-pf-3 off
    alias net-pf-6 off
    alias net-pf-9 off
    alias net-pf-11 off
    alias net-pf-12 off
    alias net-pf-19 off
    alias net-pf-21 off
    alias net-pf-36 off

    [/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
    blacklist microcode

    [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
    remove iwlwifi \
    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

    ##### rc.local ##########################

    grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

    ##### pm-utils ##########################

    ##### udev rules ########################

    ##### dmesg #############################

    [    3.463133] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
    [    7.742859] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
    [    7.742879] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
    [  517.970390] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
    [  550.225866] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
    [  610.574063] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
    [  619.678173] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
    [ 1058.568937] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8enter code here042:654c426c

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: can you please format your post? See the formatting guide https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Here, this is what I have used for my RTL8821. It works perfectly.

Make sure that you have `git` and `dkms` installed (`sudo apt install dkms git`).

`mkdir -p ~/build` - create a dir to build in.

`cd ~/build`- cd into that dir

`git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git`- clone the repo that we need

`cd rtl8821CU`- cd into the new dir that we just cloned

`sudo ./dkms-install.sh $USER` - now build the package.

This may take a few minutes, depending on your hardware. When its done, you're wifi should be working. If not, comment and I'll continue to help. Cheers

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you said CE, not CU. Ill update my answer with the proper git clone.

Comment: I would like to point out (if its not obvious by the name of the github) that this is not an official realtek driver. You can read more about it (which i suggest that you do, and not just trust strangers on the web) by copying and pasting that url into your web browser. cheers

Comment: Do I need to reboot after I have done all those operations or should it work right away?

Comment: In my experience, i have to just unplug it then replug it if its a dongle. You may need to reboot since its PCIe.

Comment: also, after you reboot, go check the `software and updates` program, and look under the `additional drivers` tab. see if you see anything for the wifi adapter then. Had you checked that previously? Sometimes on new systems i have to manually install the drivers from that tab, by inserting a wifi dongle to get wifi access, and then going to that tab and selecting the driver and installing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I rebooted and checked software and updates in additional drivers tab and it says "No additional drivers available".

Comment: hmm, try doing this real quick `sudo modprobe 8821ce`. also, i guess that with this solution, it is required to have secure boot disabled in your bios

Comment: you may actually need to turn the secure boot off before you use the modprobe command

Comment: yeah, i guess that dkms modules will not work on systems with secure boot enabled. according to here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Comment: In my BIOS menu I don't have secure boot option. Does it mean it is enabled/disabled or non of the above?